# JHipster Service Provider Error

Tags: angular, service, jhipster, provider

I encountered a problem that probably has a simple solution that I'm sadly ignoring. I hope someone will help me.

Basically I generated a new app with a `.jdl` file that perfectly did the work.

Now I'm trying to use this simple app but I get an error while clicking on "Add {Entity Name}". 2 entities give me this error.

These are `.ts` files.

The first is `Quiz` entity that has a relationship with `Question`.

`quiz.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SERVER_API_URL } from '../../app.constants';
import { Quiz } from './quiz.model';
import { ResponseWrapper, createRequestOption } from '../../shared';

@Injectable()
export class QuizService {...}
```

`question.service.ts` is made in the same way as `quiz.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SERVER_API_URL } from '../../app.constants';

import { Question } from './question.model';
import { ResponseWrapper, createRequestOption } from '../../shared';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {...}
```

I only paste these ones because the problem is the same in the 2 entities.

I thought that the problem was in `app.module.ts` so I made providers' imports but this didn't solve the problem.

`app.module.ts`

```
import './vendor.ts';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Ng2Webstorage } from 'ngx-webstorage';

import { ConductionTestsSharedModule, UserRouteAccessService } from './shared';
import { ConductionTestsAppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { ConductionTestsHomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { ConductionTestsAdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { ConductionTestsAccountModule } from './account/account.module';
import { ConductionTestsEntityModule } from './entities/entity.module';
import { customHttpProvider } from './blocks/interceptor/http.provider';
import { PaginationConfig } from './blocks/config/uib-pagination.config';

import { UserProfileService } from './entities/user-profile/user-profile.service';
import { QuestionService } from './entities/question/question.service';
import { PositionService } from './entities/position/position.service';
import { CustomUserService } from './entities/custom-user/custom-user.service';
import { QuizService } from './entities/quiz/quiz.service';
import { ResultService } from './entities/result/result.service';
import { RoleService } from './entities/role/role.service';

// jhipster-needle-angular-add-module-import JHipster will add new module here

import {
    JhiMainComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ProfileService,
    PageRibbonComponent,
    ErrorComponent
} from './layouts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ConductionTestsAppRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
        ConductionTestsSharedModule,
        ConductionTestsHomeModule,
        ConductionTestsAdminModule,
        ConductionTestsAccountModule,
        ConductionTestsEntityModule,
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
    ],
    declarations: [
        JhiMainComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        PageRibbonComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ProfileService,
        customHttpProvider(),
        PaginationConfig,
        UserRouteAccessService,
        UserProfileService,
        QuestionService,
        PositionService,
        CustomUserService,
        QuizService,
        ResultService,
        RoleService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ JhiMainComponent ]
})
export class ConductionTestsAppModule {}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:

Error log:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[QuestionService]: 
  StaticInjectorError[QuestionService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for QuestionService!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js?593e:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js?593e:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js?593e:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js?593e:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js?593e:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js?593e:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js?593e:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js?593e:10883)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js?593e:12111)
    at resolveDep (core.js?593e:12609)
```

`.yo-rc.json` file here.

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "it.manuelgozzi.conductiontest"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.13.2",
    "baseName": "ConductionTests",
    "packageName": "it.manuelgozzi.conductiontest",
    "packageFolder": "it/manuelgozzi/conductiontest",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "cdda7ac3158dc63769dac817269341c665e771fb",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

I add JDL here.

```
entity Role {
    roleName String
}

entity CustomUser {
    password String,
    enabled Boolean,
}

entity UserProfile {
    firstName String,
    lastName String,
    email String,
    contact String,
    domain String,
    expLevel Integer
}

entity Position {
    description String,
    domain String,
    status String,
    createdBy String,
    createdOn LocalDate
}

entity Quiz {
    startDate LocalDate,
    endDate LocalDate,
    status String,
    marks String
    questionsNumber Integer,
    complexity String
}

entity Question {
    section String,
    description String,
    optionA String,
    optionB String,
    optionC String,
    optionD String,
    answer String,
    marks String,
    status String,
    complexity String
}

entity Result {
    obtainedMarks String,
    percentage Double,
    appearedOn String,
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    CustomUser{position} to Position
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Quiz{questions} to Question
}

relationship OneToOne {
    CustomUser{userProfile} to UserProfile{customUser}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    CustomUser{role} to Role
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Position{quiz} to Quiz
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Quiz{result} to Result{quiz}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Question{quiz} to Quiz
}
```

Comment: Where is the text of the error?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I forget to add it. I made an edit, please check it. @Gaël Marziou
I only posted one case because the second one is the same stack trace... Glad if you help me, thanks.

Comment: Could you please help me out there?

Comment: So you made no changes to app generated by JHipster and it does not work? Running 4.13.3 ? Could you share your git repo or at least .yo-rc.json and jdl import file?

Comment: I added the `.yo-rc.json` file. I tried to make changes injecting QuestionService into QuizService but my JHipster build seems to not receive changes. I changed a bit the html files just to test if it gets changes and the result is that JHipster continues to build older version... I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I am building project with `mvn -Pdev` command.

Comment: JDL file please

Comment: First you should use both mvnw and yarn to see hot reloading of changes in client part. See doc http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

Comment: I added JDL file. If I run yarn start it doesn't take Dev profile... I rebuild the project every time I make a change using mvn. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163146/discussion-between-gael-marziou-and-manuel-gozzi).

Answer (score 0):

Talking with G. Marziou helped me to find the solution.

There were different problems.

1) Launching build with terminal command without `sudo` didn't compile all the files due to an `EACCES` hidden error (terminal didn't show that).

2) Once launched the console gave the error of a generated `component.ts` file.
It seems that JHipster generated this code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-user-profile',
    templateUrl: './path of the template',
    providers: [NameOfTheService]
})
```

that I edited removing `providers`.

Once done I built it and it worked. I'm using MAC OS Sierra, maybe this post can be helpful for someone, so I decided to share the same.

Special thanks to Gael for his amazing support. JHipster is a very well done product, its team is absolutely amazing in supporting and assistance.

Keep it up, guys!

Comment: If you need to run sudo then it means your setup is wrong and doing so is very dangerous because you download unknown software from the internet (maven , npm). Search on google about how to fix your environment, for node use nvm, change ownership of your user directories, ...